# Notification Sounds in Kubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, notification

@Nmath

Notification sounds won't work. I have already noticed notification tab in system settings; but it doesn't have anything there. If you are suggesting that "Configure events" tab, there is a section for "Play a sound"; but nothing installed there. Isn't there a package or something for automatically installing event/notification sounds just like windows? (Session opening sound, shut down sound, error sound etc.)

Technically it should work, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure notification sounds under **System Settings > Notifications**.

On the primary tab of the notifications system settings module, you can make adjustments to options that affect all notifications:

[image: Screenshot of Notifications Tab]

Since notification *sounds* are different depending on the application and the action, you will need to click the **"Configure"** button next to **"Applications:"**.  This will reveal a list of applications that send notifications to KDE:

[image: Screenshot of Application Settings for Notifications]

Choose the application you want to configure and click **"Configure Events..."**.  This will open a pop-up window for the selected application and allow you to configure notification sounds for events in that application:

[image]

Every application has different options depending on how the software sends notifications to KDE.  Some applications might not have any configurable options under "Configure events".  This might be because the application doesn't send notifications to be handled by KDE.

Comment: Hello there, Firstly, thank you for your reply and sorry for the delay that I wasn't able to reply your post. The problem is I already know that option in the KDE settings and that what I was asking in the first place. Question 1: Is there a default event sounds in KDE or not? My KDE is completely silent. Question 2: Is there a package for configuring events for all the applications and for system sounds? Because setting them one by one is complete torture. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: 1) Yes, by default, system sounds *should* be enabled for a variety of tasks in a variety of applications.  This is the case with a clean/fresh installation; 2) Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any package or method for changing many notification sounds at the same time however; 3) What might work is if you create a new user.  This will create brand new configs for the new user and everything should be as it is in a clean installation- if that works, you could migrate to the new user.

Comment: My installation is pretty new, I installed it a few weeks ago. I created a new account but it didn't work. I tested sound on youtube. The sound is working but there is no event sounds, complete silence. What would you suggest? And by the way, does your event sounds work?

Comment: On my current installation, I have disabled them myself, but on a new install the default notification sounds are enabled and working.  On your installation when you go through these manually, are they all disabled? Or are sounds enabled for several tasks and you just don't hear them?  If the latter, there could be an issue with your sound configuration and not notifications.

Comment: I didn't try to configure it manually; because it seemed pointless to me as there are tons of event sounds. But by default, there is only 1 event sound and it is the sound setting itself: 1) I "left-click" on sound icon in the system tray 2) When I try to change speaker volume I can hear an event sound. But that's all. Where are "logout sound", "logged in sound" etc. I used windows for almost two decades, so I'm extremely used to those system sounds. I don't know why I want it like an addict, but this is the situation :(

Comment: ... and what about an application that isn't listed in the "Configure Events..." list? In my case, kdialog is not emitting any sound. The handlers in the "Plasma workspace" specify a sound for question, warning, error; other system warnings do actually emit such configured sound, but not the ones shown by kdialog. I tested KUbuntu 20.04 and 21.04 fresh installations on VMWare; it used to work on my previous VM with KUbuntu 14.04