# Ricoh-SP111 only prints blank pages

Tags: drivers, printing, ricoh

I've a printer Ricoh-SP111 and for installing the driver I have followed suggestions here:

[Ricoh SP111 printer setup help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641405/ricoh-sp111-printer-setup-help#764963)

I installed it without any errors; however whenever I try to print something, I get blank pages. For example, if I print a document with 5 pages, the printer prints out 5 blank pages. I think it acts like it printed, but it doesn't. Could anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Ya.. same thing happen to me. print only blank pages... i tried the below steps. its working fine.. but i don't understand the logic :) https://superuser.com/questions/1563140/printer-printing-only-one-blank-page-ricoh-sp-111

Comment: Unbelievable! Thank you so much my friend! It's also worked for me :) I don't care for the logic, I can finally print :) I have Kubuntu 20.10. Maybe you can help me for my last problem here :) -----> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292303/notification-sounds-in-kubuntu-20-10/1292889?noredirect=1#comment2200506_1292889